# Recover .jpg from thumbs.db database files

Tags: android, database, windows

I'm desperate to retrieve photos from some thumbs.db files. My friend recently died, so I'm really in a hurry to recover all the photos of him. I don't know how to do it however, I've tried Thumbnail Viewer and a SQLite, without success.

How I got the files: Around 5-6 years ago I stored some photos and folders in my old phone from a PC (WindowsXP). Next, the computer crashed and I only got the photos in the phone (Samsung S1). And now, after several years, I really need hem, but I don't got the unlock details of the phone any more. Therefore, I connected the device to my laptop (Windows7) and I managed to transfer the files. It turned out that they were thumbs.db files.

I don't have any knowledge about this. But I found Thumbviewer to see what's in there. There I saw that there were so many photos that I need.

Comment: [IThumbnailCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774628.aspx).

Comment: IInspectable, I don't know anything about programming. That is why I ask for help here. I hope someone could help me that could do it for me with compensation in return. Can I contact you in some way?